# Javascript function does not return values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a JS function that is supposed to accept an id as argument, lookup the array of objects, and return the object. while it prints the called object, but it does not return it.

I have tried assigning the object to a variable and return this variable, that does not help.

```
const events = require('../models/events');

const allEvents = events.allEvents;

const getConnections = function() {
    return allEvents;
}

const getConnection = function(cid) {
    allEvents.forEach(event => {
        if(event.connectionId == cid) {
           // console.log(event)
            return event
        }
    });
}


module.exports = {getConnections, getConnection}
```

while `console.log(event)` prints the event, `return event` returns undefined.

Here is the calling code:

```
const con = require('./connectionDB')
const data  = con.getConnection(3)
console.log(data)
```

The actual output should be the event details.

Comment: returning from a inner function doesn't magically return from the enclosing function. You're only returning from forEach (which doesn't make sense since forEach returns undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getConnection` does not return anything. [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is what you need:

```
const getConnection = function(cid){
    return allEvents.find(event => {
        return event.connectionId === cid;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop a forEach...
use the find method.

```
const getConnection = function(cid){
 return allEvents.find(event => event.connectionId == cid);
}
```

Comment: There's no sane way to stop forEach @Karl-AndréGagnon

Comment: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description

Comment: @chrispbacon my bad, you are right, I mixed up my languages.

Answer (score 0):

Returning from an inner function doesn't magically return from the enclosing function. You're only returning from `forEach` (which doesn't make sense since forEach returns undefined). `forEach` also isn't the right choice here, what you wanted to use was `find`

```
const getConnection = function(cid){
    return allEvents.find(event => event.connectionId === cid);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because in `getConnection` you are returning inside of the `forEach` callback. You'll have to use `find` and return the value that's *found* from the *find* method

```
const getConnection = function(cid){
    return allEvents.find(event => {
        if(event.connectionId == cid){
           // console.log(event)
            return event
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will return `undefined`